# Exercise 2.1. (chapter 1) of Hale (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am sorry for the elementary question. I would like only to confirm if there isn't anything wrong with my solution.

In Jack Hale's book on ODEs, pag. 17, exercise 2.1, he asks for the following.
"For $ t, x $ scalars, give na exemple of a function $ f(t,x) $  which is defined  and continuous on an open bounded connected set $ D $ and yet not every noncontinuable solution $ \phi $ of (1.1.) defined on $ (a,b) $ has $ \phi (a+0) $ , $ \phi (b-0 ) $ existing."

Obs.: (1.1) is the usual $ x'(t)=f(x,t) $.

Firstly, I found it hard to understand his notation of $ \phi (a+0) $ and $ \phi (b+0 ) $. I looked to his previous results, and I still do not fully understand it. So, if you could explain to me, I would appreciate it.

Secondly, I think that "noncontinuable" means a solution that could not be extended to $ a $ and $ b $. If this is not the case, please correct my conceptual flaw.

Thirdly, it seems to me that the $ f(x, t) $ equals to the derivative of 
$ \displaystyle\frac{1}{(t-a)(t-b)} $ would suffice. That is to say,

$$ f(x,t)=\frac{a+b-2t}{(t-a)^2(t-b)^2} $$
Am I right?

Fourthly, even if I am right, is there another interesting exemple. For instance, an example in which it would have a diferente behaviour?

Finally, thank you very much for your attention. I like very much this platform.
I have already used this platform, but only reading answers and questions of others as an undegrad student. This is my first time asking a question, and the first time I took the initiative of registering.